# Changing the Billing date in the mid of subscription in Braintree

Tags: php, sdk, payment-gateway, server-side, braintree

Already I have more subscriptions with Braintree gateway. Now I want to change the billing date of some subscriptions not all.

Is there any possibility to change the next billing date in braintree subscriptions?

Comment: show what you have done so far.

Comment: I have created a subscription for a customer with yearly renewal but now I want to make one year free for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree.</sub>

You cannot change the billing date on an existing subscription, you must cancel the subscription and create a new one. However, if you want to give someone a free year, you can apply a discount to their existing subscription. 
First, [add a discount](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/add-ons-discounts) from the Braintree Control Panel  for the cost of one month of the subscription, with a duration of 12 billing cycles.

Then using the API you can add this discount to the subscription:

```
$result = Braintree_Subscription::update(
  'theSubscriptionId', 
  'discounts' => 
    [ 'add' => 
      [ 'inheritedFromId' => 'your-discount-name' ]
]);
```

Comment: Thanks @jessica-d. It works for me by giving an discount to the users in the subscription.